# Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module" Simple Screen Recorder

Tags: gtk, system-failure

Just recently, when I run: `simplescreenrecorder`, I get this error message:

```bsh
Gtk-Message: 00:44:36.847: Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (5.15.2) with this library (5.15.3)
zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)  simplescreenrecorder
```

How can I make this error go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to update the package: `qt5-styleplugins`

Comment: It's good that this solved the issue that you had, but it's unfortunate that you couldn't give more details about the cause of the issue and how updating that particular package actually solved it.